# Update an array in JSON Object property

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, discord.js

I am making a discord bot in which i have created a `config.json` file, where i am storing the channels id added by the add_channel command and i want to remove them though the rmvchannel command. But when i am running the below code, instead of only deleting the value spliced function is making the whole array blank.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let jsonInput = fs.readFileSync('config.json');

if (!jsonInput) return console.log("NO JSON FOUND");

let jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonInput);

var config = jsonData;

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("rmv_channel")
    .setDescription("Remove Channel Command")
    .addChannelOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("channel")
        .setDescription("the channel")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
  async execute(interaction) {
    let channel = await interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id;

    let array = await config.channels;

    let index = array.indexOf(String(channel));

    array.splice(index, 1);

    config.channels = await array;

    var json =  JSON.stringify(config);

    fs.writeFileSync("config.json", json);

    interaction.reply({ content: "Channel Removed !!" });
  },
};
```

this is config.json file

```
{
"channels":[]
}
```

i tried this code by modifying it but nothing seems to work

Comment: Why `await config.channels` and  `await array`?  Those are synchronous operations.  And are you saying that, if you start with 3 entries, it deletes them all?  Your example doesn't show that.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have tried it doing by not using await but still it was making the array blank. so i tried it using await but the result is still same

Comment: And why not just `config.channels.splice(index,1)`?  Do you have some evidence that the channels are getting ADDED?

Comment: @TimRoberts `config.channels.splice(index,1)` I have used it, result is still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this a little differently.
I use the following data in the config file to recreate your use case.

```
{"config":["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8","id9"]}
```

I wrote this very basic logic to filter out the id you no longer want.

```
const fs = require('fs');


let jsonFile = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
let data = JSON.parse(jsonFile);

const newData = {config: data.config.filter((e) => e !== 'id1')};

fs.writeFileSync("config.json", JSON.stringify(newData));
```

All I do is read the file, parse it to Json, filter the config property to anything that isn't id1 and then write that to the file.

This is the result I get after running that simple example.

```
{"config":["id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8","id9"]}
```

In theory you don't need to add await to any of the operations as you have done.